# Which data is being used for violin plot?

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, ggplot2

Sorry I just got totally confused conceptually.

If this is my raw count data

Likely, Seurat divides each value by sum of the column afterward times by 10000.

which gives so

```
                   s1.1        s1.2 s1.3       s1.4 s1.5
DDB_G0267178 0.00000000 0.009263254    0 0.01286397    0
DDB_G0267180 0.00000000 0.000000000    0 0.00000000    0
DDB_G0267182 0.00000000 0.000000000    0 0.03810585    0
DDB_G0267184 0.00000000 0.000000000    0 0.00000000    0
DDB_G0267188 0.02640801 0.000000000    0 0.01286397    0
```

Literally Seurat claims that final step would be taking natural log of the above matrix as I tested with

```
library(seurat)
mat <- matrix(data = rbinom(n = 25, size = 5, prob = 0.2), nrow = 5)
mat

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    2    2    3
[3,]    1    1    1    1    2
[4,]    1    1    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    3
mat_norm <- LogNormalize(data = mat)
mat_norm
[1,] 7.824446 .        7.824446 7.419181 7.014015
[2,] 7.824446 .        8.517393 8.112028 8.112028
[3,] 7.824446 8.517393 7.824446 7.419181 7.706713
[4,] 7.824446 8.517393 .        7.419181 .       
[5,] .        .        .        7.419181 8.112028
```

My confusion is: seurat@data dose not give me natural log transformed data rather returns only data divided by column sum and scalled by 10000.
So when plotting a violin plot if data are log normalised plot should not look as below picture

When I used

```
VlnPlot(object = y, features.plot = "DDB_G0277853", x.lab.rot = FALSE, y.log = TRUE)
```

plot changed totally. Could someone please help me in getting idea about seurat@data that is not really log transformed and by which data violin plot is being produced??? So if a gene has 10000 read counts, without log transformation violin plot should be so

This is my seurat object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normalized and log-transformed values are used for the violin plot.
The argument `y.log` changes only the display of the data (scaling of the y axis).

Seurat has very good documentation. [Section 7 in the FAQ](https://satijalab.org/seurat/faq) explains what data is stored in the object:

> 7. How is data stored within the Seurat object? What is the difference between raw.data, data, and scale.data?
>
> **raw.data** The raw data slot
> (object@raw.data) represents the original expression matrix, input
> when creating the Seurat object, and prior to any preprocessing by
> Seurat.
>
> **data** The data slot
> (object@data) stores normalized and log-transformed single cell
> expression. This maintains the relative abundance levels of all genes,
> and contains only zeros or positive values. See ?NormalizeData for
> more information. This data is used for visualizations, such as violin
> and feature plots, most differential expression tests, finding
> high-variance genes, and as input to ScaleData (see below).
>
> **scale.data**
> The scale.data slot (object@scale.data) represents a cell’s relative
> expression of each gene, in comparison to all other cells. Therefore
> this matrix contains both positive and negative values. See ?ScaleData
> for more information.

Comment: Thank you, you are definitely alright. The problem is; when I am normalising values for some genes and compare them with output of seurat@data, some genes are ok, but some genes seems to be without log normalisation and all stored in seurat@data. I guess maybe after calling by 10000, only some especial range of expression values go through the log normalisation, for example seurat@data gives me 0.0026 for a gene in a cell, when I calculated  by pen, I noticed this value is just deciding the raw count on column sum multiply by 10000. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In your first example, the last row does not match: DDB_G0267186 vs DDB_G0267188. Note that object@raw.data contains all cells, meanwhile object@data contains only the filtered cells. That might explain the difference.

Comment: @FereshTeh look for comparison at [the formula](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/185#issuecomment-338299619) Seurat uses: `log1p(value/colSums[cell-idx] *scale_factor)` (note the implicit _+1_ and _logn_ in the formula)

Answer (score 2):

Those two graphs don't look radically different.   The y axis is definitely not log scaled on the top one, and it looks like it is scaled in the second one (y.log = TRUE)

Comment: Sorry, what you think about logNormalize function in Seurat that does not return log  transformed data?

Comment: Sorry, for instance, for gene 1 in cell 1 I have 1040 RAW read counts. the sum of raw read counts in cell 1 for all genes is 373762. Based on the seurat documentation for normalisation, I should do so;  ln ( 1040/373762 * 10000) that gives me 3.6 that is right. So in top violin plot for this gene seurat has used the natural log transformed data as stated and in seconds violin plot I am just taking another log of y axis. But question is: why seurat@data does not return values as I expect and I called for one gene rather give me only scaled data by 10000. could you help me?